# Abstract Algebra: Normal Subgroups

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups

Show that, if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, $a \in G$ and $n \in N$, so exist an element $n' \in N$ $|$ $an=n'a$.

Comment: In many books, this is the definition of normal subgroup ($\forall a\in G, \forall n\in N, ana^{-1}\in N$): which is yours?

Comment: The book I'm using is "Álgebra Modena" from Hygino H. Domingues.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't got it at hands... What definition of normal subgroup does it report?

Comment: A subgroup N of a group G is called "normal subgroup" if, ∀ x∈G, we have xN=Nx.

Comment: Ok, so $xN=Nx \Rightarrow xN\subseteq Nx$; now deploy the definition of set inclusion by using the quantifiers, and you' ll find your statement.

Answer (score 2):

$an=ana^{-1}a$, write $n'=ana^{-1}$, $n'\in N$ since $N$ is normal.